# How to get a value from a select for a variable in javascript

Tags: jquery, django

I am trying to get a value from a variable. console.log ($ ('# id_prova'). val ()) works perfectly when inspecting element, console.log (proofIdQuestao), which is part of app.js, does not work. I want to make one dropdown dependent on another. The questions depend on idProva.

app.js

```
    let urlQuestoes = $('#myForm').data('urlquestoes');
    var provaIdQuestao = $('#id_prova').val()
    console.log($('#id_prova').val())
    console.log(provaIdQuestao);
    console.log(urlQuestoes);
  $('#questaoSelect').change(function() {
    let urlQuestoes = $('#myForm').data('urlquestoes');
    let questaoIdQuestao = $(this).val();
    console.log(questaoIdQuestao);
    $.ajax({
    url: urlQuestoes,
    data: {
      questao: provaIdQuestao
    },
    success: function(response) {
          $('#provaSelect').html(response);
        }
    })
  });
});
```

base.html

```
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</script></head>
```

index.html

```
<form action='/pesquisa' id="myForm" method="GET" data-urlquestoes="{% url 'questoes_choices_ajax' %}" data-urlcategorias="{% url 'categorias_choices_ajax' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="card acik-renk-form">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="provaSelect">Provas</label>
          {% render_field form.prova title="Provas" class="form-control" %}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="questaoSelect">Questões</label>
          <select class="form-control" name='questao' id="questaoSelect">
        <option value="">---------</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="categoriaSelect">Categoria</label>
          <select class="form-control" name='categoria' id="categoria">
        <option value="">---------</option>
        {% for categoria in categorias %}
       <option value={{categoria.idCategoria}}>{{categoria.nomeCategoria}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Termo" type="text" name="q" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-md btn-primary pl-6 pr-6">Pesquisar questões</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Where is `id_prova` in the html?

Comment: {% render_field form.prova title="Provas" class="form-control" %}

Comment: Where is `app.js` included in your file?

Comment: static/js/app.js